# Trying to Unit Test Generic Repository based on .NET EF Core fails when dealing with DbContext.Entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have written a generic repository (BaseRepository), where it's **Delete** method code is:

```
    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (dbContext.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbContext.Attach(entity);
        }
        dBContext.Remove(entity);        
    }
```

I want to unit-test the code. Since the DbContext is an external dependency, I just want to verify that when I will call the **Repository.Delete(entity)**, then eventually the **DbContext.Remove(entity)** is to be called once. However, I have to Mock the behavior of dbContext.Entry... just before the actual dbContext.Remove(entity) call.
The Unit Test code is:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Delete_SomeEntityToRepository_CallsTheAddMethod_To_DbContext()
    {
        // Arrange
        var testObject = new Customer()
        {
            Name = "Test-Customer"
        };
        
        var dbContextMock = new Mock<DbContext>();
        var dbEntityEntryMock = new Mock<EntityEntry<Customer>>();
        
        dbContextMock.Setup(d => d.Entry(testObject)).Returns(dbEntityEntryMock.Object);
        dbEntityEntryMock.Setup(e => e.State).Returns(EntityState.Unchanged);
        
        // Act
        var repository = new CustomerRepository(dbContextMock.Object);
        repository.Delete(testObject);

        //Assert
        dbContextMock.Verify(x => x.Remove(It.Is<Customer>(y => y == testObject)), Times.AtMost(1));
    }
```

However this code crashes, and actually at line:
`dbContextMock.Setup(d => d.Entry(testObject)).Returns(dbEntityEntryMock.Object);`
with message:
**Can not instantiate proxy of class: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry`1[[Fx.CommonTests.DataAccess....**

System.ArgumentException
Can not instantiate proxy of class: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.**EntityEntry`1**[[Fx.CommonTests.DataAccess.Customer, Fx.CommonTests, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
Could not find a parameterless constructor. (Parameter 'constructorArguments')...

Obviously the DbContext.Entry(...) is the problem. So, any ideas, about how to mock this???

I tried various variants of the code, as found in several articles, about how can I mock such cases, but always the end was the same. Any Ideas?

Comment: Why wrap a generic repository in a generic repository in the first place?

Comment: The Generic Repository is an abstract class defining all basic crud functionality for the generic TEntity. So it very much makes sense, to create a CustomerRepository : BaseRepository<Customer> because this way, you get out of the box all basic crud functionality with 1 line of code.

Comment: Entity Framework already has all that.

Comment: You can send to EntityEntry's constructor an instance of [InternalEntityEntry](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/e846c0c0518220c81520cec616ba682fa3272612/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/Internal/InternalEntityEntry.cs#L36-L39) But EF is not intended to be tested in this way.

Comment: @daniherrera I do not intend to test EF, this is external dependency and does not need testing from me. Testing my Repository is my intention. So the deal is to verify that method A called from Repository , triggers the correct method(s) with correct arguments in DbContext. This is my intention.

Comment: @ThemisZarotiadis I shared an answer regarding how to prevent the test error, but I believe that there may be a different approach to consider when designing this test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can Mock dbcontext to prevent the test error, but I believe that there may be a different approach to consider when designing this test (see `but` section below):

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Moq;

// ...
```

```cs
[Fact]
public void Delete_SomeEntityToRepository_CallsTheAddMethod_To_DbContext()
{
    // Arrange
    var testObject = new Customer();

    var internalEntityEntry = GetInternalEntityEntry(testObject);

    var dbEntityEntryMock = new Mock<EntityEntry<Customer>>(internalEntityEntry);
    dbEntityEntryMock.Setup(e => e.State).Returns(EntityState.Unchanged);

    var dbContextMock = new Mock<DbContext>();
    dbContextMock.Setup(d => d.Entry(testObject)).Returns(dbEntityEntryMock.Object);

    // Act
    var repository = new CustomerRepository(dbContextMock.Object);
    repository.Delete(testObject);

    //Assert
    dbContextMock.Verify(x => x.Remove(It.Is<Customer>(y => y == testObject)), Times.AtMost(1));
}

private static InternalEntityEntry GetInternalEntityEntry(Customer testObject)
{
    return new InternalEntityEntry(
        new Mock<IStateManager>().Object,
        new RuntimeEntityType(
            name: nameof(Customer), type: typeof(Customer), sharedClrType: false, model: new(),
            baseType: null, discriminatorProperty: null, changeTrackingStrategy: ChangeTrackingStrategy.Snapshot,
            indexerPropertyInfo: null, propertyBag: false,
            discriminatorValue: null),
        testObject);
}
```

*Full text here: https://gist.github.com/ctrl-alt-d/3d10384a06fa1e0c515e1f182fb83bb0*

### **But** (<- big "but"):

- You shouldn't do it:
  https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27110
- Read about how to write tests when you use EF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking
- If I were to write a test for your generic repository, this is how I would approach it: https://gist.github.com/ctrl-alt-d/8bc8d1f9e41a8ea98309397c46933fe4

Comment: Thank you very much. I also tend to agree that unit-testing Repository & Unit-of-Work patterns, can and should go up to the extent of verifying that the Repo/UoW actually calls the correct method to Context.
For this, usage of InternalEntityEntry you have mentioned can help. If it is absolutely needed it can do. For more extensive tests, when possibly also more complexity is involved, then a set of **Integration tests** is needed. As also you have named your test sample gist with. So, these are integration tests and are needed to assert a significant level of code quality.